# How to prove that a function sequence converges uniformly and to find an integral

Tags: uniform-convergence

I have to prove that the function : $f(x)=0$, if $x=0$ and $f(x)=\frac {1}{[\frac {1}{x}]}$, if $x\in (0,1]$ is integrable and to find the integral $I=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

I define $f_n(x)= 0, x\in [0,\frac {1}{n+1})$ and $f_n(x)=\frac {1}{k}, x\in (\frac {1}{k+1},\frac {1}{k}], k=1,2, ..., n$.

Now there are some problems :
(a) Does the sequences converge to f uniformly?

(b) Trying the theorem, I find that I is equal to $\frac {\pi ^2}{6}-1$, but is that correct ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: I imagine $f_n(x)=1/k$ for $x \in (1/(k+1),1/k]$?

Comment: Yes ! You are right.It was a typo and I correct it.Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Yes the sequence converges uniformly. Indeed, let $\epsilon>0$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $\frac{1}{N+1} < \epsilon$.

Also, notice that by definition, $f_n(x)=f(x)$ on $\big{(}\frac{1}{n+1},1]$. Also, for $x \in [0,n+1]$, $0 \leq f(x) \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Therefor, for $n \geq N$ and for $x \in [0,1]$, we have that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{n+1}<\epsilon$. We deduce uniform convergence.

For your evaluation of the integral, that is correct according to my calculations, but you should add how you came to that value in your post!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, you are right about the way of evaluation of the integral.I omitted the way, hoping to add it later, if the answer was wrong.I Appologize for this. I simply take the integral of $f_n (x)$ on $[0,1]$. By the main  property,we take :

Comment: We have $I_n=0+\Sigma (\frac {1}{k+1}-\frac {1}{k}+\frac {1}{k^2}) $ and the rest is obvious.Sorry but I could not write the math text to LATEX. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I must add that the first two terms in $\Sigma$ form a telescoping sum.